# Combine PHP Statements

Tags: php, if-statement

Using this code:

```
<div class="venus"><span class="ricon">Established</span><span class="locko"><?php the_field('br_estd'); ?></span></div>
```

However, I need to wrap this within another PHP IF statement:

```
<?php $mista = get_field('br_presence'); if ( strval($mista) == 'Worldwide') {echo "PLACE CODE ABOVE HERE" ;} ?>
```

How could I syntax this?

Comment: I tried 1 million things but keep getting errors, what do you mean !?

Comment: Look into separating your PHP and HTML.

Comment: You should always include your efforts (in other words, what you've tried and what that resulted in), as well as your complete code and error messages. This will make it possible for us to help and advice you with the problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does have an [alternative syntax format for control statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) that work well within HTML, although it is generally recommended to use templates and keep logic out of your view as much as possible. That being said, you could do something like:

```
<?php if (strval(get_field('br_presence')) == 'Worldwide') : ?>

    <div class="venus">

        <span class="ricon">Established</span>

        <span class="locko"><?php the_field('br_estd'); ?></span>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

could be you are looking for

```
  <?php 
      $mista = get_field('br_presence'); 
      if ( strval($mista) == 'Worldwide') {
        echo '<div class="venus">
              <span class="ricon">Established</span>
              <span class="locko"><?php the_field("br_estd"); ?></span>
          </div>';
        //echo "PLACE CODE ABOVE HERE" ;} 
  ?>
```

Comment: `<?php the_field("br_estd"); ?>` - should remove the `<?php` and `; ?>` - you're already inside php/echo ;-)